# Проектирование БД. Хранение путей к файлам в одной таблице или в нескольких

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование

Собираю базу данных. Задача найти оптимальное (наиболее производительное) решение модели базы.

Дано:

> - таблица с сотрудниками **"hrms_employees"**;
> - каждый сотрудник имеет паспорт (таблица **"hrms_passports"**), сертификаты (таблица **"hrms_certificates"**), образование (таблица **"hrms_educations"**);
> - документов у каждого сотрудника может быть несколько (2 сертификата, 3 диплома образования и тд);
> - каждый документ сканируется и загружается в систему, пути к документам сохраняем в таблице **"hrms_docs_paths"**;
> - Таблица **"hrms_docs_paths"** связанна с **"hrms_passports"** таблицей **"hrms_passports_docs_paths"** отношением многие ко многим. Аналогичная ситуация с **"hrms_certificates"** и **"hrms_educations"** (см. модель ниже).

Вопрос:

> Оптимальное ли данное решение связей с точки зрения
>   производительности, либо лучше отказаться от таблиц
>   **"hrms_passports_docs_paths"**, **"hrms_сertificates_docs_paths"**, **"hrms_educations_docs_paths"** в пользу хранения всех путей напрямую в таблице **"hrms_docs_paths"** с добавлением двух индексов:
>   **id_document** (ключ в основной таблице документов) и **type** (passport,
>   education, certificate)?

Текущая реализация:
**(На типы данных не обращайте внимание, сейчас набрасывается общая модель.)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Одна таблица - правильное решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Одна** таблица для сканов, **одно** поле типа enum для типа скана (или отдельная таблица с типами, если они будут динамические и пополняемые).

И, главное, не хранить пути к файлам в базе. Каждый скан так или иначе имеет уникальные признаки - идешка, тип, владелец. Дата создания на худой конец или контрольная сумма от файла. Всего этого достаточно для генерации путей до файла.

Завтра поменяете способ хранения файлов и придётся обновлять все записи в базе? Нет, только поменяете генератор путей. Плохая идея хранить весь миллион файлов в одной папке. Вы всё равно рано или поздно придёте к шардированию в том или ином виде. Базы это никак касаться не должно.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу свой вариант.

Создайте 3 таблицы.

1. **hrms_employees**
2. **hrms_docs_paths**
3. **hrms_docs_type**

1 и 2 таблицу свяжите общим ключом, возможно это будет какой-либо ID или номер табеля сотрудника в организации.

2 и 3 таблицы свяжите id_type

В конечном итоге запрос по сотруднику условно говоря будет такого вида

```
SELECT empl.*, doc.passport, doc.certificates FROM hrms_employees empl
JOIN hrms_docs_paths doc
ON doc.id_empl = empl.id_empl
WHERE empl.name = 'Иванов'
```

Если хотите выводить название документа, в запрос вкладываете **JOIN** по **hrms_docs_type**, где будет 2 стобца: **id_type**, **type_name**

С точки зрения проектирования такой вариант будет предпочтительней, чем для каждого типа документа создавать отдельную базу.